# i cant get my calculator to work

Tags: java, string, user-input, calculator

i want to input a int to get first number then use a string to get the operator and another int for the second number. user should input some thing like 10+20.
but as soon as i enter the "+" then i get an error why?

cuz it works if i manually add the values into the sum.calc(); myself like sum.calc(12, "+", 24); then it works ill get 36

```
PART 1:
import java.util.Scanner;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    math sum = new math();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double a = input.nextDouble();
    String b = input.nextLine();
    double c = input.nextDouble();
    sum.calc(a, b, c);
    input.close();
}


PART 2:
public class math {
public void calc(double a, String b, double c){
    double t;
    switch(b){
    case "+":
        t = a + c;
        System.out.println(a+" + "+c+" = "+t);
        break;
    case "-":
        t = a - c;
        System.out.println(a+" - "+c+" = "+t);
        break;
    case "*":
        t = a * c;
        System.out.println(a+" * "+c+" = "+t);
        break;
    case "/":
        t = a / c;
        System.out.println(a+" / "+c+" = "+t);
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). - please [add](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) the *complete* error message you get.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: 17
+
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
 at Testing.TestInfo.main(TestInfo.java:14)

Comment: it worked :D YAY! thanx im new to java but thanx now i learned something new! you where a great help "Thank You!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `input.next();` instead of `input.nextLine();` Because `input.nextLine();` advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. so if your input was 20, +, and 24, your method `calc` would get 20,24,null.

Comment: it worked :D YAY! thanx im new to java but thanx now i learned something new! you where a great help "Thank You!

Comment: please mark it as answered if you are satisfied with the answer by clicking the _check_ below the answer point of your chosen answer

Answer (score 1):

input.next() works instead of input.nextLine() for strings.Try it out