# I want to find the percentage

Tags: java, int, percentage

i want to find the 25% value of any int or double like

int 100 - 25% should = 75 or
int 200 - 25% should = 150 etc

how can i do something like that in JAVA

Comment: Are you asking how to do basic arithmetic?

Comment: Java would really be a pitiful language if it couldn't ...

Comment: This question shows absolutely no research or knowledge of basic mathematical principles. Just sayin'.

Comment: :D you have to learn how to do it using regular math

Comment: 100 - 25% can be written as `int x=100; x = (int) (x * 0.75);`

Comment: I'm afraid you have to use * *dramatic pause* * math.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, if you post a question here always add what you've tried as well (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question/284237#284237).
Your question is basic math btw, and easily doable with basic java.

Comment: @Socowi Or `int x=100; x = (int) (x * 0.75);`

Comment: @khelwood That would explain his other question: [i cant get my calculator to work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42760429/982149)

Answer (score 2):

You should divide 25 by 100 and then multiply with the number you want percentage of. Try this:

100 - (100 x 0.25).

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple math in Java to return the value as required.

`double percentageValue = myIntValue - (myIntValue * 0.25);`

"myIntValue" represents any integer that you can set up as required.